# Why is memcpy seg faulting?

Tags: c++, memcpy

So I know that the following code can use '=' and be much easier and better, but I'm trying to understand memcpy better for more complex applications. When I use "ptr = b", i get an output of "1", which is what I expect. In using memcpy, it segfaults.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int *b = &a;
    void* ptr;
    memcpy(ptr, b, sizeof(b));
    int *c = (int *)ptr;

    cout<<*c<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"but I'm trying to understand memcpy better for more complex applications"*. Actually, there is rarely a reason to use `memcpy` in c++ at all.

Comment: Well I just started a new job and am trying to understand the code they already have in place, and they used memcpy with some void pointers (which i had never seen until yesterday) so I'm trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ptr` does not point to anything, so attemp to change data it points to leads to crash.

You probably want to do `memcpy(&ptr, &b, sizeof(b));` (Change value of `ptr` itself)

Comment: Also, even if `ptr` points to something, `sizeof(b)` should probably by `sizeof(*b)`.